# Delay Time Before Going Into Another Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need a code to delay the form behind it go into another form. For Example 
There will be a form to type in your name and then there will be a button to be click to show all the detail (which means it will do a dlookup first). I need to have a delay for the person to confirm the detail is correct before it go to the next form.

```
Private Sub btnLog_Click()
Me.txtName.Value = DLookup("FullName", "tblUsers", "txtIC = " & "IC")
```

What Can I Type In Here To Delay The Form Before It Do The Next Command Which is Below

```
DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "fblMenu"
```

Comment: Please try adding relevant tags. The target audience can help you better. It is difficult to understand if it is a web/desktop application written in Java/C#

Comment: You've said what you need here, but not asked a question. Stack Overflow is a Q&A website for when you've tried and failed to solve the problem yourself. What you're doing here is requesting the volunteers do the work for you; SO isn't a free coding/consultancy services. This clearly isn't SQL Server related  as SQL Server doesn't have "forms". This is related to some kind of programming language. Personally I would suggest deleting this question,  reading the [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) pages again, and ask a new question that fits in the guidelines, with the right tags.

Comment: What does SQL Server have to do with this question?

Answer (score 0):

Use this API call (in the Declarations' section of the code module):

```
' API call for sleep function.
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```

Then, in your code, insert the time to sleep in milliseconds:

```
Sleep 2000
```

That said, it is poor design to slow down an application.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Access. I tried to use the code above but wasn't above to work. It pop out an error.

Comment: It is perhaps the simplest of all API calls, and it cannot fail. For an implementation, peruse here: [VBA.ModernBox](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernBox/blob/master/ModernBox.bas).